# stress testing new ram appears to fail

Tags: memory

i have upgraded from 2G ram to 8G ram following [the recommendations on cricial.com](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=OptiPlex%20745%20Series%20%28Desktop%20Mini-Tower%20and%20Small%20Form%20Factor%29) and the new memory is being recognised:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7933       4791       3142          0         37       4076
-/+ buffers/cache:        677       7256
Swap:         4075          0       4075
```

i want to make sure that all the ram is working fine so i tried a simple `stress` test but i get errors:

```
$ stress --vm 7G --vm-bytes 1B
stress: info: [29232] dispatching hogs: 0 cpu, 0 io, 7516192768 vm, 0 hdd
stress: FAIL: [9884] (347) fork failed: Cannot allocate memory
stress: FAIL: [9884] (347) fork failed: Cannot allocate memory
stress: FAIL: [9884] (347) fork failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

and this just goes on forever.

**firstly**, have i used the `stress` command correctly? the documentation is a bit sparse, but the relevant section says:

```
Usage: stress [OPTION [ARG]] ...
 -m, --vm N         spawn N workers spinning on malloc()/free()
     --vm-bytes B   malloc B bytes per vm worker (default is 256MB)
     --vm-stride B  touch a byte every B bytes (default is 4096)
     --vm-hang N    sleep N secs before free (default is none, 0 is inf)
     --vm-keep      redirty memory instead of freeing and reallocating
```

as i understand it, my above command is getting 7G threds to each use one byte of memory, and since my system has 8G then there should be plenty of memory available to do this. is this actually what the above command does? and if so then is this the correct way to test if all the memory is working?

**secondly**, do the above errors indicate that there is a problem with my ram?

Comment: You only have 3G free per the first result, so asking for 7G is probably not going to fly, unless you free up more memory before asking for it. You also don't appear to have increased swap, as it's still 4G (right size for 2G RAM, 1/4 what you want with 8G RAM)

Comment: cheers! all good info!

Comment: *"my above command is getting 7G threds"* — did you really intend to create 7 billion threads? :-)

Comment: heh yeah i did, but i wasn't sure if this was the proper way to test that the ram is working correctly :P the man page for the stress command is really sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, according to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stress), you are not using the command properly. Try:

```
stress --vm 1 --vm-bytes 7G
```

Try adjusting the vm parameter as you see fit. Note that [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) is generally considered a far, far better test of your memory.